# Unity3d - Objects turn invisible when built on iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a game that is fully ready for android, but during the process of getting it to work on iOS I noticed that the instantiated objects weren't visible in iOS. I can confirm they were there as they have colliders on them that send a game over signal when they collide and after a couple of seconds I do get gameover (when they collide). It's just that they're not visible. Also, this works fine in Unity. I only get the problem after building to iOS and I don't get the problem when I build to android.

**EDIT**

This is a 2d game so sprites are being rendered. Again the instantiated objects are there and functioning as they should just the sprites are not being shown on the screen

Comment: You might want to share more details about how you render the objects (shader, 2d, 3d, materials,...). do any error appear in Xcode? try the Xcode OpenGL ES Frame Capture feature to see if the rendering order might be wrong.

Comment: I edited the question. I will look into the OpenGL thing later as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Within limited information provide in the question I can only answer to your problems is that:* There are some limitation for iOS build which includes Graphic limit:

1. **DXT texture compression is not supported**; use PVRTC formats instead.
   Please see the Texture2D Component page for more information.
2. Rectangular textures can not be compressed to PVRTC formats.
3. Movie Textures are not supported; use a full-screen streaming playback
       instead. Please see the Movie playback page for more information.([More](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-unsupported.html))

You should also need to check [texture override](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporterIos.html) in unity for iOS.

*Remember: No one can answer with the limited information you can also do iOS Debugging yourself through [this Guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TroubleShootingIPhone.html).*

Comment: I am using DXT texture compression right now, but I noticed that PVRTC format requires POT Textures. Is there anything else I can use that doesn't require me to use POT textures? I don't want to have to remake all the sprites into POT textures.

Comment: use DXT texture compression not supported on iOS, for alternative PVRTC i can only recommend you to read unity official textures docs https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html

Comment: Turns out Unity automatically converts NPOT textures to POT textures when using PVRTC compression. I'm going to test this out later today. http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/875885/view.html

Comment: After building it worked. Thanks! I wouldn't have figured this out without you.